# Help requiring a npm module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I feel like I'm missing some very basic here...

So I install a npm library with `npm install somelib`.  And from what I have read I should then be able to simply do a

```
var somelib = require('somelib');
```

But it fails to find anything.  I do have a `node_modules` directory at the root of my app, but it doesn't seem to pick it up.

I tried `require.paths.push('node_modules')` but it doesn't help.  The only thing that seems to work is this:

```
require.paths.unshift('.');
var somelib = require('node_modules/somelib/lib/somelib');
```

Which makes me feel like this is far more work than I actually need to do to load a npm library.  What am I doing wrong here?  I thought that installing modules in the app meant I didnt have to futz with environment variables or paths much?

Comment: what are you trying to install? What platform?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your first example is how it should work. Are you using npm 1.0 ?

Comment: It is possible that a package `somelib` does not have a file named `somelib`. It is also possible the installation is misconfigured.

Comment: Actually `js2coffee` but I just tried with `express` and that worked fine.  I guess not all npm modules can be `require`d in this way? Isn't requiring the whole point of an npm module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471965/what-will-be-the-difference-in-requiremypackage-js-and-requiremypackage/15471995#15471995

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that `somelib` does not have a `main` file defined in their `package.json` or that it is incorrectly referenced. If `somelib` doesn't have a `main` but does have a `directories.lib` then you can do `require('somelib/thefile.js')` instead.

If `somelib` is written in coffeescript and your app isn't, you'll need to `require('coffee-script')` first.

**Update:** as `js2coffee` is coffeescript, I'm going with you need to do the latter.

Comment: Is it ok to require all npm modules in a single server.js file... or we have to create separate files.... what is the best practice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Having the specific module name instead of "somelib" might help... but check the package's `package.json` file. Display the `require.paths` and compare. Read up on node's [module system](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html#loading_from_the_require.paths_Folders)