# How to use NPM modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I'm completely new to frontend web dev with a very basic question.  Once I `npm install` something, how do I actually use it?  For example, I just did `npm install bootstrap`, and I would now like to be able to use the CSS and Javascript that it downloaded.  I'm sure I shouldn't have to dig through the directories to find some entry point... so how do I now *use* bootstrap in my webpage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help requiring a npm module in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463684/help-requiring-a-npm-module-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

Most modules on NPM are used in Node.js, for the server (backend). Node.js has a built-in function `require('your-module')` to make use of the module. This function is not present on the frontend in the browser. However, there are tools like `browserify` or `webpack` and probably others to make the NPM modules and the `require` function work in the frontend.

If you're just starting out I suggest you take a look at [Bower](http://bower.io/) first. With Bower (installed with NPM though) you can pull in all your frontend libraries like jQuery, Bootstrap, etc. to your project folder and you can point your script tags in your HTML to the `bower_components/` directory, e.g. `<script src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`. You can save a list of all libraries used with a version number in a json file called `bower.json` in the root of your project folder. 
Based on this file you can pull in or update all the libraries listed with the use of the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As a really general rule, npm is used for assets your node app will use on the server, while bower (and others) are the equivalent for dependencies that you want to use on the client.

That said, the use is basically the same.

npm (and bower) install the files into your project directory in a standard location.  All you really have to do is make sure that location is accessible via a web request (typically, node_modules is not; which is why bower came about), and then embed link and script tags as appropriate in your html:

```
<script src='/node_modules/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```